# speed of preorder traversal

Tags: time-complexity, graph-traversal

I want to know the speed of preorder traversal of  an tree. I do not mean its order of magntude which we know is O(n).
I want something like 27n  operations where an operation is precisely defined.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not answerable in the abstract, without a lot more specifics.  It depends on intimate specifics of the computer architecture, what counts as "one" operation, how the tree is represented, and many other details that are usually considered a distraction for purposes of analysis of algorithms.  And it wouldn't really be useful in practice anyway; these days, the time it takes for an algorithm to complete depends on a lot more than the number of operations.  Not all operations take the same amount of time, and more importantly, the memory hierarchy plays a huge role in influencing the running time, and you can't measure its impact by counting operations.

Comment: From a book about the ancient 68020 processor: “Calculating exact execution times is very difficult even with complete knowledge of the processor architecture” (quoting Motorola engineers from memory). Today… forget it. Even measuring execution times in a meaningful way is hard.

Comment: Today, one algorithm isn’t on its own. It is often possible to make one algorithm run faster at the expense of other processes running on the same computer. For example, a computer with 12MB cache shared between 4 cores. If your algorithm takes advantage of more memory (12MB instead of its 3MB share) it may run faster but make other processes slower.